# Integral involving heaviside theta function evaluated at boundary of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to know how to compute an integral of the form

$\int_0^t dt' \int_0^{t'} dt'' \delta(t''-t)f(t',t'')$

where $f$ is finite for all $t'$, $t''$ over the ranges of integration, and $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta "function". I suspect that zero is the most sensible answer? Is the above integral zero if we assume that

$\int_0^t dt' \delta(t'-t) ={1\over 2}$.

Put differently, I think we can evalute the $t''$ integral to get

$\int_0^t dt' \theta(t'-t)f(t',t)$,

where $\theta$ is the heaviside step. It seems like this integral should be zero? Is this the case even if we adopt the convention $\theta(0)=1/2$?

Thanks for your help!

Later amendment: I think I have an argument for why the integral is zero, which goes as follows, let

$f(t',t) = {\partial g(t',t) \over \partial t'}$.

Now integrate by parts to get

$\int_0^t dt' \theta(t'-t)f(t',t) = {1\over 2}g(t,t) - \int_0^t \delta(t'-t)g(t',t) = {1\over 2}g(t,t) -{1\over 2}g(t,t).$

I would still like to know if there are conventions for the definitions of $\delta$ and $\theta$ on the boundary, which allow the integral to be computed, but lead to a non-zero value.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{t}\dd t'\int_{0}^{t'}\dd t''\delta\pars{t''- t}\,\mrm{f}\pars{t',t''} \\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{t}\,\mrm{f}\pars{t',t}\braces{%
\bracks{t < 0}\bracks{t' < t < 0} + \bracks{t > 0}\bracks{0 < t < t'}}\dd t'
\\[5mm] = &\
-\bracks{t < 0}\
\underbrace{\int_{t}^{0}\,\mrm{f}\pars{t',t}\bracks{t' < t}\dd t'}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
\bracks{t > 0}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{t}\,\mrm{f}\pars{t',t}\bracks{t' > t}\dd t'}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ =\
\bbx{0}
\end{align}